Hashicorp Vault Reading Policy
I'm trying to define an access policy where the user can see the secret, but not its value.
If I leave it with the "list" capability, the secret is not shown, when I put "read" it shows the value.
How can I resolve it?
The policy created returning error:
path "apv/secrets/+/boom" {
 capabilities = ["create", "update", "delete", "list"]
}

The policy returning the values
path "apv/secrets/+/boom" {
 capabilities = ["create", "update", "delete", "list", "read"]
}

I tried use /* in the but I was unsuccessful
The policy only shows the key and not the value in the path.

From my understanding, Vault does not support directly listing the individual keys within a KV secret. If you're using KV version 2, you could utilize the metadata associated with the secret. For instance, you could create metadata keys that match the names of the keys in your secret, but set their values to describe the purpose of the secret, provide a brief description, or include details like the last modification date or a planned rotation date. So then you could have a policy like this:
path "apv/secrets/metadata/boom" {
 capabilities = ["read"]
}

